# Fitting img inside div

Tags: css

I have an div

which I keep box shaped all the time using:

```
div{
    float:left;
    width:  447px;
    height:     445px;
    background-color: blue;
}


div:after{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   padding-bottom:100%
}
```

the problem occurs when I want to add an image to the div

```
<div><img src="as.jpg"></div>
```

using:

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Does one of the two things:

1. the image does not cover whole div
2. the image does not cover whole div and box shape is ruined

Is there a way how to fix this? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ddbpd98c/)

Comment: Why are you using padding-bottom: 100% in '.small:after'?

Comment: You mean like this - https://jsfiddle.net/ddbpd98c/2/

Comment: @fdey so the div will keep box shaped every time.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **image as background-image**.

Example :

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
  background: url('http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/729223main_728322main_messenger_orbit_image20130218_2_full_full_full.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

If you would like to **use [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)**, its simpler.

Example (using Bootstrap):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/love_wallpaper_vector_3d_wallpaper_261.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="padding-top: 5px">
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also do it the usual way, just set the height of the image.

Image in a div, **with image height defined** :

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/love_wallpaper_vector_3d_wallpaper_261.jpg" alt="image" height="200px" />
</div>
```

Comment: the background-image works fine , but what if i want more divs with different images? Thats just mor classes. Is there a way using img inside? That would also work for others element , in case i do not want to add just an image.

Comment: @trolkura read through again. I have given three solutions. Use the third one(__with image height defined__) if you just want img in div.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the parent element, hence the `div.small` hasn't its height explicitly set.

For elements `height` is `auto` by default, meaning every element has height equal its contents. Contents of an element determine its height.

For an element to have `height: 100%`, hence to use percentage to fit in container's height, you should determine the height of the parent in absolute value.

Try this:

Try set for example `height:400px;` to `div.small` and `height: 100%;` for the image. Then the image will fit its container.

Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/esu7jtbp/).

**Update**

Also, please check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E6vRltmJNI) by [lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/), as it provides an explanation about elements height. A bit old, but very good stuff.